Testflight view sessions for newest build only
In Testflight, how can I view the total sessions-per-user for only one build in an external tester group?  Right now, I can view total sessions for all builds combined, but I want to see total sessions per user for only this build.
If a user has sessions from previous builds, those are currently included in the total session count.  I want to eliminate the sessions from previous builds in the session count.
If this cannot be done in Tesflight, is there another way to view this for an external testing group?


Unfortunately, this cannot be done. You can view all sessions for specific build but you cannot get it for a specific external testing group.
The only other way come to mind, is using app store connect APIs:
you can get the metrics for each tester in the external group you want and filter the data by time to get a semi accurate readings.
"data" : [ {
    "type" : "appsBetaTesterUsages",
    "dataPoints" : [ {
      "start" : "2022-10-05",
      "end" : "2023-10-05",
      "values" : {
        "crashCount" : 0,
        "sessionCount" : 21,
        "feedbackCount" : 1
      }
    } ]


You can already get the metrics for each tester in the portal and add a time filter, but this does not remove the testers that have recent sessions with older builds
